# Hide status bar on initial load screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to hide the status bar (top bar with time and signal strength etc) while my inital load screen is displayed. Sorry if this is obvious, but I'm a new at this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By setting `UIStatusBarHidden` on your `Info.plist` you can control the starting status (hidden, or shown).

To hide it (or show it) within you application, you need to use:

`-setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` on `UIApplication` (docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:))

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a field called UIStatusBarHidden to your info.plist and set it to boolean true (not a string 'true').

Comment: thanks. this works but I want the status bar on when the app i running just not during the load screen and now its off all the time

Comment: Huh? The loading screen should be the same as the initial screen of the all with all text and details removed. The lay-out should be the same.

Comment: Not working for me ... I want to hide status bar on splash screen but by setting UIStatusBarHidden as YES in info.plist doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the info.plist, set UIStatusBarHidden to YES. It will automatically convert to "Status bar is initially hidden" to YES in the info.plist. In the appdelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method, add the following line of code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

     application.statusBarHidden = FALSE;
```

by adding this line of code the status bar is displayed after the splash screen is loaded.